# Selenium able to verifyElement, unable to access/use those elements

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

So as the title says, when I use a verifyElement and search by ID, the test does not crash.  But when I try to enter data (specifically into a textBox) the test fails.

The textbox:

```
<span><input type="text" name="searchString" maxlength="100" value="" id="searchString" class="commonTextBox"></span>
```

This does not fail:

```
automation.verifyElement(AutomationConstants.FIND_ID, "searchString", false);
```

This fails:

```
automation.enterInputBox(AutomationConstants.FIND_XPATH, "//input[@id='searchString'and @class='commonTextBox']", "Alex", false);
```

I have also used FIND_ID instead of XPATH, which also fails.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Just verify in firebug how many elements are there with same locator.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access the page in anything but IE.

Comment: :( . Use driver.findElements(By).size() to figure out how many elements are there with same locator.

Comment: Well how it does fail?

Answer (score 0):

Test will not crash on verification. You should use Assert instead of Verify. In this case you will be sure that element really contains what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchString'and @class='commonTextBox']")).sendKeys("YOUR TEXT");
```